# What is your workflow for skinning Flex apps?

Tags: apache-flex, skinning

Also, where do you start if you want to create a **complete** Flex 4 skin? Is there a list of all the "pieces" (component parts) you need to create graphics for somewhere, or some complete, example skins out there to use as a template? And do your skins render correctly in Flash Builder Design View? (including embedded fonts)

Comment: I, personally, hire a designer to skin a Flex app.  I recommend you take a look at Flash Catalyst, which is the Adobe answer to complex skinning of Flex 4 Spark components.

Comment: Catalyst kind of sucks, sadly. Like Spark itself, it's just not "ready". Anyway, who's going to hire someone to work on an open source or free utility? Adobe made this more complicated than it used to be!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most people will point you to Flash Catalyst, but the last time I looked it was not all-inclusive in terms of creating a complete skin/theme, not to mention other issues inherent to 1.0 software.  I start by copying the default skin files and modifying them, as well as creating a new CSS file based on the defaults.css file that comes with the SDK.  The trickier part is that not all components (Tree, DataGrid, DateChooser, ColorPicker, etc) are available as Spark components, which means to have a complete skin/theme you need to create a bunch of mx skins as well.  Bottom line: If you are serious about doing this properly, you'll need to spend a lot of time understanding defaults.css and the skin classes it refers to.

To answer your original question, my personal workflow is to create a mockup of the skin in OmniGraffle, then use that as a guide to modify copies of the default skin files (look in spark.skins, and mx.spark.skins) by manipulating the mxml directly (as opposed to using a graphical tool such as Illustrator or Catalyst.)

Hope that helps.

Comment: +1 Flash Catalyst is nice in theory, but it's a long way from finished at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you have many options when skinning Flex 4 apps :

- Using "general" styles (chromeColor, selectionColor, focusColor, ...). This is usually called "Styling" instead of Skinning because you only change the overall look of the application. It's by far the easiest way to change the appareance of your application quickly without knowing anything about FXG, MXMLG, ... The drawback is it will still look like a Flex app, but with different colors/fonts
- Using Adobe tools to produce FXG files. These tools can be Illustrator, Photoshop, Flash CS5. You design each of the spark component with these tools and export the result in .fxg format. FXG is great because it's [optimized](http://butterfliesandbugs.wordpress.com/2009/10/02/optimized-fxg-vs-runtime-fxg-aka-mxml-graphics/), but you can't use things such as Data Binding in it
- Write your skin in MXMLG , by hand (starting from scratch or copying the default spark skin) or with the help of Flash Catalyst. Catalyst can take your Illustrator or Photoshop design and convert it to MXMLG. Experience shows it's still painfull, even with the last version. And you often end up doing things like [this](http://danny-t.co.uk/index.php/2010/10/27/fla-to-fxg-to-flex-4-spark-skins).

In our team, there is no such thing like designer/developer workflow with Flash Catalyst. The next version looks better but it's still far from what Microsoft is doing with Visual Studio/Blend.
That being said, the new Spark architecture is awesome. Skinning is much easier, flexible and readable. With this architecture, a developer codes the component and the designer skins it only by knowing the contract (skinparts, skinstates, data)
This also true for views if you use the Presentation Model pattern.

There is no "template" skins as the one available in Flex 3 because skinning doesn't use symbol anymore. What could be done though is a Flex 4 style explorer.

A final word, it has already been said here, but don't forget that with the current version (4.1), there is no spark equivalent for all of the components, so you  will still use Flex 3 skinning techniques for components such as DataGrid, Tree, ...

Comment: Obviously Spark isn't ready and now we're going to end up with a bunch of 'hybrid' component apps as a result until that's fixed, what a mess. I would like to know what the "contract (skinparts, skinstates, data)" entails--how and from where does the designer get this information?

Comment: You have 2 options :
- Looking at the component ASDoc. SkinParts and SkinStates are detailled there
- When you create a new Skin with Flash Builder (that is not a copy of an existing Skin), it generates automatically the SkinState definitions and tells you which SkinPart are defined on the host component

Answer (score -1):

This is where I normally "start"

http://examples.adobe.com/flex2/inproduct/sdk/explorer/explorer.html

Once I figure out what components I have to skin, and I can't change what I want to change in Flex with CSS, then I go into Flash and start breaking the components apart and tweaking them.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/skins_styles.html

(Also, I've never had **anything** render "correctly" in design view)

Comment: He's looking for Flex 4 skinning techniques

Comment: Then he should start here http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex4_skinning.html

Comment: That technique (and even design view, for the most part) worked in FB3... but they've completely broken it in FB4.  Flash shouldn't be needed to skin a Flex app, that sucks.